# CSS styling of text input not working in Safari

Tags: html, css

CSS styling of an input element is working fine in Chrome, but it is not applied in Safari.
Any tips?

```css
#searchTerm {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #676c6e;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
  color: #ebebeb;
  background-color: #2f3437;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="searchTerm" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="What are you looking for?" autofocus>
```

Comment: What parts of it are not applied? I just checked with Safari on an iPad Pro (2018), and looks the same as on Windows/Firefox.

Comment: No styling is applied at all, Safari 14.0.2 on MacOS.

Comment: I've noticed that the code snippet worked, but not on my website. Can you check https://notionicons.website as well?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
Adding the following fixed the problem.

```css
input {
    -webkit-user-select: text; /* Chrome, Opera, Safari */
    -moz-user-select: text; /* Firefox 2+ */
    -ms-user-select: text; /* IE 10+ */
    user-select: text; /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Comment: You still have not even explained what the problem was. If you are not willing to even clearly describe the problem, why are you looking for help on SO?

Comment: makes perfect sense to me...